# How to remove goto statement from iterator

Tags: c#, iterator

I'm implementing a simple [iterator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) over an xml document, in order to process an xml document in as much a streaming manner as possible. For this reason, I'm using an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5.aspx) variable in a `while` loop.

This iterator must either return each first-level child elements, depending upon the name of the root tag. Otherwise, it should return the single root element as a whole.

In order to return an xml element, I have a choice of using [XNode.ReadFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.readfrom.aspx) or [XmlReader.ReadOuterXml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml.aspx). Both of which perform an additionnal read on the [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5.aspx) variable. Therefore, I must find a way to prevent reading past interesting data in the underlying xml.

The first draft I came up with had a `goto` statement that I now would like to avoid, without sacrificing readability. Here is the code:

```
    public IEnumerable<XElement> Elements()
    {
        while (reader_.Read())
        {
        next_element:
            switch (reader_.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    {
                        // This is a composite document
                        // skip to first-level elements
                        if (reader_.LocalName.StartsWith("CompositeDocument"))
                        {
                            RootNamespace = reader_.NamespaceURI;
                            IsComposite = true;
                            continue;
                        }

                        var element = XNode.ReadFrom(reader_) as XElement;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(element != null);
                        yield return element;
                        goto next_element;
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

A first attempt to remove the `goto` statement, involves using two embedded loops, and a boolean flag indicating whether to stay in the inner loop or break back to the outer loop. I feel this makes the code less readable. Here is the code:

```
    public IEnumerable<XElement> Elements()
    {
        while (reader_.Read())
        {
            var inner_loop = true;
            while (inner_loop)
            {
                switch (reader_.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        {
            // this is a composite document
            // skip to first-level elements
                            if (reader_.LocalName.StartsWith("CompositeDocument"))
                            {
                                RootNamespace = reader_.NamespaceURI;
                                IsComposite = true;
                                inner_loop = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var element = XNode.ReadFrom(reader_) as XElement;
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(element != null);
                                yield return element;
                                inner_loop = true;                                    
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                    case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                    case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                    case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                    case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                    case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        inner_loop = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason I'm inclined to keed the goto statement is that, in iterators, the `yield` statement is already akin to a `goto` statement, albeit to the next line of code.

Please, can anyone suggest how to best rewrite this code snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do it with a boolean and short circuiting your while loop condition?

```
...
    var isElement = false;
    while (isElement || reader_.Read())
    {
        isElement = false;
        switch (reader_.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                {
                    // This is a composite document
                    // skip to first-level elements
                    if (reader_.LocalName.StartsWith("CompositeDocument"))
                    {
                        RootNamespace = reader_.NamespaceURI;
                        IsComposite = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var element = XNode.ReadFrom(reader_) as XElement;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(element != null);
                    yield return element;
                    isElement = true;
                }
                break;
...
```

Comment: This must have been one of my 'Doh !' moments...

Comment: It brings up an interesting point.  Some people would argue that the goto version is cleaner / easier to read.  I don't think I'm one of those people though.